# Xubuntu 15.04 Gummiboot Kernel Panic

Tags: boot, kernel, xubuntu, uefi

So I installed my new Xubuntu 15.04 in EFI mode. I installed gummiboot via `sudo apt-get install gummiboot` and activating `sudo gummiboot install`.
On my HP Notebook I have to enter the efi file as custom boot as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554690/hp-uefi-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-automatically): `EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`

(Without switching to gummiboot, namely booting with `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`, works)

Unfortunately I get a kernel panic when trying to boot, as seen in this screenshot

[image]

Did I miss anything important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the kernel options passed via gummiboot are different from those passed via GRUB. In particular, the gummiboot configuration is probably missing a `root={whatever}` option (where `{whatever}` is a description of your root filesystem, such as a UUID or device filename). See [the gummiboot web page](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot/) for details about gummiboot configuration files.

Comment: I had an error in the options flag of my config (namely an error in the root variable ;) ). It's an honor that you answered my question (as the creator of refind)- Thanks a lot!