Ubuntu loops itself on HP logo after installation
My HP laptop doesn't boot Ubuntu automatically. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 five times, but when I restart it or start the laptop it stops on the HP logo and then restarts again like it's in a boot loop.


read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. There's nothing here on which even to attempt a response

@graham Let's see what you think about it now after correcting the spelling errors. The OP also posted a deleted non-answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/554690/ one hour ago, so I think I know what he's asking about this time.

Does this answer your question? Reset system boot loop after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on HP ProBook

What if you tried installing Ubuntu Server 24.04 on your laptop? Ubuntu Server boots to a text login screen. Then you can install the complete Ubuntu desktop system metapackage (ubuntu-desktop) on top of Ubuntu Server and use it as a desktop operating system including the default Ubuntu graphical login screen.
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

